# Collect search occurrences with rscopus in r?

Tags: r, find-occurrences, scopus

I have to make a lot of queries on Scopus. For this reason I need to automatize the process.

I have loaded "rscopus" Package and I wrote this code:

```
test <- generic_elsevier_api(query = "industry", 
                             type = c("abstract"), 
                             search_type = c("scopus"), 
                             api_key = myLabel, 
                             headers = NULL, 
                             content_type = c("content"),
                             root_http = "http:/api.elsevier.com", 
                             http_end = NULL, 
                             verbose = TRUE, 
                             api_key_error = TRUE)
```

My goal is obtaining the number of occurrences of a particular query.

In this example, if I search for "industry", I want to obtain the number of search results of the query.

```
query      occurrence
industry     1789
```

how could I do?